# Recommendations on integrating Craft 3 and FormAssembly

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice.

We have a client that we are in the process of moving away from a Drupal build to a new Craft build, however, they have a large number of forms created in FormAssembly that sync nicely with Salesforce. Does anyone have experience with Craft/FormAssembly integration specifically rolling their own plugin or using the HTTPS Connector?

The client doesn't want to have to recreate all the forms, so using a plugin like Freeform isn't really an option.

Any other insights greatly appreciated.